# ruby on rails implement list control with an "add" button and a text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table of recipes, each recipe has several ingredients. In the "new recipe" form,
I want the user to be able to add the ingredients.

I planned to add a list control with a text field and an "add" button (the text field will either auto complete the ingredients from my "ingredients" table or create a new ingredient).
The user is expected to add the ingredient in the text field, press the "add" button, and then the ingredient should be displayed in the list box. Then the user can go on and add the next ingredient.

It seems like it should be the simplest control ever but I can't seem to find a way to implement it in rails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a nested form, in that a recipe has many ingredients - Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 which will give you a good idea as to how to implement it.

Comment: recipe indeed "has_and_belong_to_many" ingredients and vice verse. I will check the screen cast right away and see if it can solve my problem